# What is a GPG with "authenticate" capability used for?

Tags: ssh, authentication, openssh, gnupg

GnuPG subkeys can be flagged with three kind of capabilities: *Sign, Encrypt and Authenticate*.

While the first two actions are widely used and documented, the authenticate action is somehow mysterious.
You can make such key only using editing a primary key with the `--expert` option:

```
$ gpg --expert --edit-key 889C36B7
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.0.17; Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
gpg> addkey    
...                  
Possible actions for a RSA key: Sign Encrypt Authenticate 
Current allowed actions: Sign Encrypt 
   (S) Toggle the sign capability
   (E) Toggle the encrypt capability
   (A) Toggle the authenticate capability
   (Q) Finished
...
```

There are rumors about GPG keys being used to do SSH authentication, but I haven't read or found a way to make it work. There are also a couple of unanswered question concerning **[gpg]** and **[ssh]** interaction:

[Are GPG and SSH keys interchangable?](https://superuser.com/questions/360507/are-gpg-and-ssh-keys-interchangable)

[How to use gpg and SSH together?](https://superuser.com/questions/378853/how-to-use-gpg-and-ssh-together)

Apart from this, I cannot find other uses for the "authentication" subkeys.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OpenPGP keys can be used for authentication in various protocols:

- SSH, as bare ssh-rsa keys (`monkeysphere subkey-to-ssh-agent`, or smartcards)
- SSH, as [pgp-sign-rsa](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6) certificates (no implementations known to me)
- TLS according to [RFC 5081](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5081) (supported by GnuTLS)
- of course, less well-known protocols and software such as gpgauth.org, Enigform, and such; they *do* find the "authentication" flag suitable.

Comment: Yes "Using OpenPGP Keys for Transport Layer Security (TLS) Authentication" is an interesting draft. But a part from that it seems that the authentication facility was added as a "bonus", but relies completely to third parties implementations. I will wait for some time to collect other answers before accepting your good one. Thanks